# the scale (zoom) of my angular application increases alone in prodution

Tags: angular, angular-material, production-environment

I develop an angular application that runs correctly under the Angular development server, but when I host it on a server Node JS the application appears very zoomed, which is good for readability but deteriorated the design. Anyone know how to fix that?

here are a expected render
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ8oZ.png)
And here the actual 
render
[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QReZ1.png)

note that the screen shoot are made at the same area

Comment: It has never happened to me before. Is the node server local or remote?

Comment: Node server is local

Comment: @Clavatar were you able to find any leads for this issue?

Comment: Also have this issue. There is a slight zoom to the page when opened on a mobile phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows it's probable that your Screen Scaling is set to more than 100%.
To check this, do the following (for Windows 10):

1. Go to Settings
2. Display
3. Scale and Layout
4. Change the size of texts, apps and other items
5. Select 100%
6. Check your app again in browser.

[image: Steps 1 - 5]